# How can I do the performance testing for react native applications in both ios and android?

Tags: react-native, performance-testing

Currently i'm using the android studio and x-code for doing my performance testing ,Is there any tools that i can use for do my Performance testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user Chrome React-Native debugger's performance tab. It's a quite advanced section where you can inspect every component and their rendering durations in milliseconds as well as network calls.

[image]